# Use PCF8574 switch selection multiple SPI slave devices, is it possible?

Tags: spi, io, expander

My project use esp8266's SPI communicate with MCP3208 and SDCard, to select which device to be communicated, that device's CS pin need to set low, and set high to another device to disable, right? My esp826 is out of pin, so my question is can I use PCF8574 to select spi device communicate with esp8266?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible to use an I2C IO expander for SPI bus chip selects. But you must decide if using it will slow down the SPI transactions too much, by analyzing how many microseconds it takes to toggle a pin via I2C.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks so much, so my only choice is use esp's pin? or is there any another solution?

Comment: If there were only two devices, you could have them both connected to the same CS pin. With a few extra components you could have CS high = (Dev1 High, Dev2 Low) and CS low = (Dev1 Low, Dev2 High). Just using it to toggle between them, you never need both low or both high right?